# IEEE 2006 Citation style puts comma inside quotation marks in bibliography

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to use Word (office) for my bibliography, and I'm using IEEE 2006 style to cite the references, but when I cite journal articles and websites, the result is this:

S. Kaplan e B. J. Garrick, «On the quantitative definition of risk,» Risk Analysis, vol. I, n. 1, pp. 11-27, 1981.

Society for Risk Analysis, «Glossary of Risk-Related Terminology,»
2015. [Online]. Available: http://sra.org/resources.

J. M. Watts e J. R. Hall, «Introduction to fire risk analysis,» in SFPE Handbook of Fire Protection Engineering, Quincy, MA, National Fire Protection Association, 2002.

Word puts the comma of the article title inside the quotation marks, which I find a bit annoying, especially since it lets me modify it, but when I update the bibliography, it goes back as it was before.

Is there a reason for this? And maybe a way to avoid this, too?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Actually, we learned in elementary school that the punctuation mark goes inside the quotation. Perhaps that is something that you forgot. For example, he said, "This is the way to do it."

Comment: Well, I'm not Englishborn, so maybe my mothertongue has different rules in punctuation. :) Anyway, it seems so pointless to me to put a comma inside the quotation marks, and not after them, as it should be more or less like a list, just with quotation marks enclosing one of the elements of the list. I have to write my dissertation in English, in my non-English speaking country, so probably most of the professors might see it as a mistake, rather than a different punctuation rule...

Comment: In English, the punctuation goes inside the quote, but outside brackets, like parenthesis. If a professor disagrees, you can always point him or her to references, e.g. Strunk and White's _Elements of Style_.

Comment: Thank you :) Then, could you explain me why in the many books I've read (written in English) and several articles, not one of them had this comma and quotation mark switch? Example: http://www.bse.polyu.edu.hk/researchCentre/Fire_Engineering/summary_of_output/journal/IJEPBFC/V6/p.28-45.pdf (just the end of the article, it was the only one I've found directly accessible without having to pay or use a special access...)

Comment: I suppose you could take the question of punctuation placement to [english.se].

Comment: Well, I suppose I should :) Thank you for your time, and sorry, I'm not sure if it was clear that the "why" in the previous comment was more of a desperate why towards the thousands of inconsistencies I've encountered with my English learning, than a sarcastic why. It's 1 in the morning here, I caught the double tone of my comment just now... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Word puts the comma of the article title inside the quotation marks

> Is there a reason for this?

Yes. That is how the IEEE have defined the styles:

> **Basic Format:**
>
> [1] J. K. Author, “Name of paper,” Abbrev. Title of Periodical, vol.
>   x, no. x, pp. xxx-xxx, Abbrev. Month, year.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> [1] M. Ito et al., “Application of amorphous oxide TFT to
>   electrophoretic display,” J. Non-Cryst. Solids, vol. 354, no. 19, pp.
>   2777–2782, Feb. 2008.
>
> [2] R. Fardel, M. Nagel, F. Nuesch, T. Lippert, and A. Wokaun,
>   “Fabrication of organic light emitting diode pixels by laser-assisted
>   forward transfer,” Appl. Phys. Lett., vol. 91, no. 6, Aug. 2007,
>   Art.ID. 061103.
>
> [3] J. Zhang and N. Tansu, “Optical gain and laser characteristics of
>   InGaN quantum wells on ternary InGaN substrates,” IEEE Photon. J.,
>   vol. 5, no. 2, Apr. 2013, Art. ID 2600111.
>
> [4] J. U. Buncombe, “Infrared navigation—Part I: Theory,” IEEE Trans.
>   Aerosp. Electron. Syst., vol. AES-4, no. 3, pp. 352–377, Sep. 1944.
>
> [5] S. Azodolmolky et al., Experimental demonstration of an impairment
>   aware network planning and operation tool for transparent/translucent
>   optical networks,” J. Lightw. Technol., vol. 29, no. 4, pp. 439–448,
>   Sep. 2011.
>
> [6] H. Eriksson and P. E. Danielsson, “Two problems on Boolean
>   memories,” IEEE Trans. Electron. Devices, vol. ED-11, no. 1, pp.
>   32–33, Jan. 1959.
>
> [7] F. Aronowitz, “Theory of traveling-wave optical maser,” Phys.
>   Rev., vol. 134, pp. A635–A646, Dec. 8, 1965.
>
> [8] Ye. V. Lavrova, “Geographic distribution of ionospheric
>   disturbances in the F2 layer,” Tr. IZMIRAN, vol. 19, no. 29, pp.
>   31–43, 1961 (Transl.: E. R. Hope, Directorate of Scientific
>   Information Services, Defence Research Board of Canada, Rep. T384R,
>   Apr. 1963).
>
> [9] E. P. Wigner, “On a modification of the Rayleigh–Schrodinger
>   perturbation theory,” (in German), Math. Naturwiss. Anz. Ungar. Akad.
>   Wiss., vol. 53, p. 475, 1935.
>
> [10] E. H. Miller, “A note on reflector arrays,” IEEE Trans. Antennas
>   Propag., to be published. *Always use this style when the paper has
>   been accepted or scheduled for a future publication, i.e., do not use
>   “to appear in.”*
>
> [11] C. K. Kim, “Effect of gamma rays on plasma,” submitted for
>   publication. *Always use this style when the paper has not yet been
>   accepted or scheduled for publication, i.e., do not use “to appear
>   in.”*
>
> [12] W. Rafferty, “Ground antennas in NASA’s deep space
>   telecommunications,” Proc. IEEE, vol. 82, no. 5, pp. 636-640, May
>   1994.
>
> [13] L. T. Wu et al., “Real-time analytic sensitivity method for
>   transient security assessment and prevent control,” Proc. Inst. Elect.
>   Eng., vol. 135, pt. C, pp. 107-117, Mar. 1988. *Authors may refer to
>   this journal as Proc. IEE, but the abbreviation must be as listed
>   above. Proc. IEE is printed in the U.K. and must not be confused with
>   the Proc. IEEE.*
>
> [14] Special Issue on Artificial Neural Network Applications, Proc.
>   IEEE, vol. 84, pp. 1353-1576, Oct. 1996.

See the [IEEE Editorial Style Manual](https://www.ieee.org/documents/style_manual.pdf)

---

#### Why am I getting a quotation mark switch?

The quotation marks used depend on the document language. I can see from your profile that you are from Italy so you are seeing the Italian style quotation marks (Word is probably configured with Italian as the default document language).

See [Why do I get “double greater/less thans” instead of double quotes in Word?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72014/why-do-i-get-double-greater-less-thans-instead-of-double-quotes-in-word) for more information.

You should set English (either UK or US) as the language for your document.

> **English**
>
> Normal English: This is a "single Quote". This is an "outer Quote
>   containing an "inner quote"".
>
> US English: This is a "single Quote". This is an "outer Quote
>   containing an "inner quote"".
>
> ...
>
> **Italian**
>
> Alternative 1: This is a "single Quote". This is an "outer Quote
>   containing an "inner quote"".
>
> Alternative 2: This is a "single Quote". This is an "outer Quote
>   containing an "inner quote"".

Source [Language Specific Quoting and Quotation Marks](http://www.witch.westfalen.de/csstest/quotes/quotes.html)

To change the document language see:

- [Customize language features in Word 2013 and later](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-language-features-in-Word-2013-and-later-8fec4c7b-150e-4226-8087-d00d5093fade)

---

#### I need a style using the numeration instead of the author(s)-year order style

You can install additional styles. One of them might be more suitable for you:

- Associação Brasileira de Normas Técnicas (ABNT)
- Association for Computing Machinery (ACM)
- American Medical Society (ACS)
- American Medical Association (AMA)
- American Sociological Association (ASA)
- Council of Science Editors (CSE)
- Harvard – AGPS
- Harvard – Anglia
- Harvard – Exeter
- Harvard – Leeds
- Humana Press
- IEEE
- Lecture Notes in Computer Science (LNCS)
- Modern Humanities Research Association (MHRA)
- Nature
- Vancouver

Source [Install additional Word reference styles (Mac + Windows)](https://www.captiga.com/tips-tricks/install-additional-word-reference-styles-mac-windows/)

You can also use a custom style to get the exact format you want. See the following links for details:

- [Bibliography & Citations 102 – Building Custom styles](https://blogs.office.com/2009/04/29/bibliography-citations-102-building-custom-styles/)
- [Create Custom Bibliography Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj851016.aspx)
- [Create new citation styles for MS Word](https://xtexterience.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/citation-styles/)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply. :) It's just that I've read several booksthat used the same IEEE style, but the bibliographies didn't have that comma and quotation mark switch. Is there (maybe) another reference style using the same structure without this "problem"? I need a style using the numeration instead of the author(s)-year order style (which is predominant in my word), and I've seen several articles using a similar style, but with commas outside quotation marks. Example: http://www.bse.polyu.edu.hk/researchCentre/Fire_Engineering/summary_of_output/journal/IJEPBFC/V6/p.28-45.pdf

Comment: @Julia The quotation mark switch is because you are not using an English version of Word (Italian?). See [Language Specific Quoting and Quotation Marks](http://www.witch.westfalen.de/csstest/quotes/quotes.html).

Comment: Caught me with the Italian Word. :D Well, I've read your link, but I'm not sure what to do with it (I'm not an expert in programming, so I'm not sure I've understood what I've just read...). I've already encountered some conflict of language mess, like the punctuation used to separate thousands and decimals in excel, which are inverted in my country, is it a similar problem? I've tried to change the language of the single reference when putting the data for it, but the result didn't change...

Comment: Yes, it's a similar problem to that in Excel.

Comment: @Julia Answer updated to cover quotation marks and downloading/creating custom citation styles.

Comment: Thank you, I see you have put further information above, I'll explore it :) The custom style is especially interesting, though maybe out of my league (all the programming I've done was in high school, with Turbo Pascal, like write the program for a ticket machine...) anyway, at least I got right with the excel comparison :) Thank you again!

Comment: @Julia You're very welcome. Do you need more help? If this answered your question(s), please don't forget to [accept it](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: No more help, you have solved all my problems :D (Accepted, I didn't know about that function, thank you again for your time)